# not repeating character from string in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting the woo-commerce product title of the first character using wp-query but I have to get repeating and my OUTPUT is AABBBCCCDDEEEEEFFFFFGGGGFFFFHHHHIIIKKLLLXXXY but I want only one character not repeating a character. My desired output should be like "ABCDEFGHIKLXYZ"

$category_query_args  = array('post_type' => 'product','posts_per_page' => -1,'post_status'         => 'publish','orderby' => 'title','order' => 'ASC',);
$category_query = new WP_Query($category_query_args);
while($category_query->have_posts()):$category_query->the_post();

//Product Title $title =  get_the_title(); $firstChar = substr($title,0,1);echo $firstChar;  endwhile; wp_reset_query();

Comment: if your making a pagination set of chars, then plop them in an array instead of echoing then you can trivially remove dupes, then loop over again. otherwise, the hack is to catch the output buffer with ob_start, echo each char as you are doing then use ob_end_clean into a variable, then split the string in into an array, remove dupes, then join back together and echo

Comment: i am not making a pagination can you tell me how can do this i am beginner

Comment: https://3v4l.org/u3avl

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i check your solution is not producing my desire output its producing like this BBBCDDDDDDDDDDDKKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLPPPPP

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the example string as source, the first part is only to have an array. Just remember the last character. When it comes to the next character, only echo it if it is different to the last.

```
$s = 'AABBBCCCDDEEEEEFFFFFGGGGFFFFHHHHIIIKKLLLXXXY';
$a = preg_split('//', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($a);

$last = '';
foreach($a as $c) {
    if ($c != $last) {
        echo $c;
        $last = $c;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, here is my string but when i complie this $s there are not producing my desire output
$s = 'A               
      A
      B
      C
      C
      C
      D
      D
      D
      D
      E
      F
      F';
    $a = preg_split('//', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    $last = '';
    foreach($a as $c) {
        if ($c != $last) {
            echo $c;
            $last = $c;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the unique characters of a string you should use count_chars(). [Documentation here](https://www.php.net/count_chars)

It should be set to mode 3 to get all the unique characters.
I used your product title in this example:

```
$product_title = 'AABBBCCCDDEEEEEFFFFFGGGGFFFFHHHHIIIKKLLLXXXY';

$product_title = count_chars($product_title, 3);

print_r($product_title);
```

Output looks like this:
[image: output]

Comment: i am trying this method is not working beacause here is my string but when i complie this $s there are not producing my desire output
$s = 'A               
      A
      B
      C
      C
      C
      D
      D
      D
      D
      E
      F
      F';
    $a = preg_split('//', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    $last = '';
    foreach($a as $c) {
        if ($c != $last) {
            echo $c;
            $last = $c;
        }
    }

Comment: You have to make your question more clear. You now have a different string, where you need to remove the spaces or what?

Comment: i have $s = 'A'
                   'A'
                   'A'
                   'B'
                   'B'
                   'C'
                   'D'
                   'D'
                    'X'
                    'Y' 
                    'Z'
                    'Z'
                    'Z';
 and i want my output is like 'ABCDXYZ' not reapeating

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. Is it an array of characters? or a string with spaces?